# How to add jlabels to a jlabel array manually in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing

I created a JLabel array:

```
private JLabel label[]=new JLabel[10];
```

How do I add the jlabels to this array in netbeans?

Comment: Please format code; see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
 JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[10];

for(int i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
 labels[i] = new JLabel("Label Name " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never used netbeans so I'm not sure if this is what you mean exactly (like some IDE shortcut or something), but you can add JLabels to an array in java by assigning the location in the array to a new JLabel.

```
    JLabel[] label = new JLabel[10];
```

assigning them manually...

```
    label[0] = new JLabel("text");
```

or all at once...

```
     for(int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
         label[i] = new JLabel("text");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't add elements to array, it is not dynamic, you can just update the entries.
Initially your array has `null` entries.

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Okocha");
label[0] = label1;
```